# How to Set the Query Logging Level for a User in OBIEE12c

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

We would like to set query log level for a individual OBIEE 12c user to diagnose the query performance of data issue. Would anyone please guide us the way of set the log level for a obiee12c user.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the query log level in obiee12c is as follows

1. In the Oracle BI Administration Tool, select Manage, then Identity.

   The Identity Manager dialog is displayed.
2. Double-click the name of the user for which you want to set the query logging level.

   The User dialog is displayed.
3. Set the logging level by clicking the Up or Down arrows next to the Logging Level field.

   To disable query logging for a user, set the logging level to 0.
4. Click OK.

Study the following document for more detail about the query log level.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIESG/logging.htm#BIESG182